# UPPAAL: Invariants violated but none have been explicitly set - how to resolve deadlock?

Tags: deadlock, modeling, verification, invariants, uppaal

I'd like to learn more about Timed Automata to verify real-time systems. Currently, I'm trying to get myself familiar with a tool called UPPAAL.

I drew some simple graphs and added different properties. The entire model is supposed to represent a production cell system where different mechanical units pass a block to each other.

I've modelled the block (*BlockCycle*), 2 mechanical units (*Feeder*, *FeederBelt*) and 2 sensors which sense the arrival of the block.

Even though I thought my system would make sense, it gets deadlocked:

> The target states of this transition violate the invariants. This is not a problem, as long as you intended your model to behave like this.

(No I didn't. ;P)

I can't seem to find the reason for the deadlock, though. The tool points me to the *BlockCycle* model but I didn't specify any invariant there. In fact, all the transition requirements are fulfilled so the transition (from *Pos7* to *Pos8*) should definitely be taken.

Below you'll see how the systems evolves and finally gets stuck (error message pops up).

[image: Model step through]

Labels:

- green : property check (e.g. *FB_Running* means *FB_Running == true* )
- dark blue: property updates/assignments
- dark red: locations (e.g. *Pos7* or *Pos8*)

The *BlockCycle* model with the respective transition in question:

[image: BlockCycle model]

My Question: Why does the system deadlock even though there are still transaction which could be taken.

---

Edit1: When I remove the invariant property of Sensor7's location *Active* (called *BlockAtPos[7]*) the deadlock is resolved. So I guess, since there is no synchronization between *Sensor7* and *BlockCycle* for the last transition before it deadlocks, that would cause to a contradiction (*BlockAtPos[7]* becoming false while the sensor has not yet the chance to take the *InActive* transition) and thus violating the invariant.

---

Note: You can find my UPPAAL code/file here: [pcs.xml](http://pastebin.com/3stjVehZ).

Comment: FYI: I posted this quesiton on math.SE before where it got rejected due to lack of mathematical nature.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this deadlock in 4.0.14 nor in 4.1.19 with the linked model. Moreover the list of enabled transitions looks different, perhaps the model is not the same.